# preg_match() to check Image urls without [img] BB tags and return boolean value using PHP

Tags: php, html

In my text field I have images enclosed within [img] BB tags like

```
[img]http://i58.tinypic.com/i3yxar.jpg[/img]
```

and plain image URLs like

```
http://www.jonco48.com/blog/tongue1.jpg
```

I want preg_match to look for plain image urls and if found return 1 otherwise 0, How to do this???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regex is quite difficult to look for a pattern without a piece, in this case the img open and closure tag.

So I would search the urls within the tag, then search all the urls and compare these counts

```
$text = "";

$tagPattern = "/\[img\].+?\[\/img\]/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $tagMatches);

$urlInTagCount = count($tagMatches[0]);

$plainPattern = "~https?://\S+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)(?:\?\S*)?(?=\s|$|\pP)~i";
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $plainMatches);

$allUrlCount = count($plainMatches[0]);

return $allUrlCount > $urlInTagCount;
```

Comment: Thanks to Clément for the url regex, I copied yours

Answer (score 1):

Using regex is really overkill for this if all you need to do is check whether or not there are `[img][/img]` tags around your string.

You can just as easily use some simple string functions:

```
function isBB($s){
    $len = strlen($s);
    return $check = substr($s, 0, 5) == "[img]" && substr($s, $len-6, $len) == "[/img]";
}

isBB('[img]http://i58.tinypic.com/i3yxar.jpg[/img]') // true
isBB('http://www.jonco48.com/blog/tongue1.jpg') //false
```

Comment: Hmm...but For this to work I have to first extract all kind of image urls with [img] tag and without it later I will loop through every URL to check if there is any url without tag

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the REGEX : `~https?://\S+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)(?:\?\S*)?(?=\s|$|\pP)~i`

In PHP :

```
preg_match('@\[img\](.+?)\[/img\]@', $your_text, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: No it didn't work as required, the string will contain both image url's with [img] tag and without it I need to check the existance of image url's without tags

Answer (score 0):

The following should work as expected:

```
<?php

$str = '[img]http://i58.tinypic.com/i3yxar.jpg[/img]';

preg_match('@\[img\](.+?)\[/img\]@', $str, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: No it didn't work as required, the string will contain both image url's with [img] tag and without it I need to check the existance of image url's without tags